# Understanding hive in mapr

Tags: hive, mapr

Why below query is not working

```
select count(*) from db.full where substr(starttime,1,10) < (select min(cast(substr(starttime,1,10) as date)) as min_date from db.v9_N where substr(starttime,1,10) between '2018-10-01' and '2018-10-10');
```

Why below query is working?

```
select count(*) from db.full where substr(starttime,1,10) in (select min(cast(substr(starttime,1,10) as date)) as min_date from db.v9_N where substr(starttime,1,10) between '2018-10-01' and '2018-10-10');
```

please help me to understand?

How to make above query workable one?

Comment: What version of `spark` are you using? Correlated sub queries are supported in `Spark 2.0+`

Comment: Im not using spark, it is in hive